# Find word in string with regex not working

Tags: regex

Why can't I match this http header with the following regular expression?

```
Via: 1.1 186.42.212.235 (Mikrotik HttpProxy) Accept: text/html, */* Host: exposurebasketballtournaments.com User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1) X-Proxy-ID: 1638425000 X-Forwarded-For: 96.255.49.253
```

with

```
^.*(Mikrotik).*$
```

Comment: It's working for me. http://regexr.com?3721f

Comment: It's working properly.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is if the header includes a line break at the end. The ``.`` doesn't normally match line breaks unless you use the single line mode.

Comment: Might you be using a drainbamaged regexp engine that regards parentheses as literals unless you escape them with a backslash (at which point they become capture group boundaries)?  This happens sometimes (Linux `grep` rather than `egrep`, "regexp" searches in certain Windows text editors, etc.)

Comment: Works for me too, but you could simplify your regex to just `(Mikrotik)` since it doesn't have to match the whole string. (In fact, a simple string match would have been fine. Why are you using a regular expression anyway?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use parentheses around the whole part you're trying to match. Try this:

`^(.*Mikrotik.*)$`

http://rubular.com/r/sCysQR3qe7